# How do i solve cannot find module 'pacote'

Tags: laravel

sourav@Sourav-Dell:/opt/lampp/htdocs/Projects/Laravel-Projects/Laravel9$ npm install
Error: Cannot find module 'pacote'
Require stack:

- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/update-notifier.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/update-notifier.js:5:16)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)

**I don't know how to fix it, please help me.**

Comment: can you try reinstalling your npm, try this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036806/how-to-remove-npm-and-reinstall-npm-completely-in-18-04)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow dear Sourav, Delete the `node_modules/` folder using the`rm -rf node_modules` command, then run npm install again.

Comment: Also please add `package.json` file to your question.